# Trace variables in template - backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Apologies for such a novice question but I'm really stuck here.

I'm working on someone's code and trying to understand it.

I have got this template 'temp.tmpl':

```
<li class="icon mu status-{{state}} type-{{type}}" style="background-color:{{colour}};">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="top-stat"><span>{{topStatNumber}}</span><span>{{topStatModifier}}</span></span>
        <span class="display-text">{{#if promotionName}}{{promotionName}}{{else}}{{name}}{{/if}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

and following view:

```
define([
  'views/toolkitView',
  'text!templates/components/temp.tmpl'
], function(ToolkitView, MUItem) {

  return ToolkitView.extend({

    template:MUItem,

    events: {
      "click a": "showActiveMU"
    },

    showActiveMU: function() {

      this.trigger("active:mu:selected", this.model.get("code"));

      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

I'm not able to figure out how variables are getting rendered in template or what template
is compiling against?

Comment: There is an additional piece of the puzzle here, probably in the ``ToolkitView`` that you are extending. Would you mind showing that code? I would warrant a guess that there is an ``initialize`` function in in ``ToolkitView`` view that renders your template with data from whatever model is assigned to the view.

Comment: You are spot on, all that is happening in ToolkitView. Do you know how `this.trigger("active:mu:selected", this.model.get("code"));` works? Please write that as an Answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for help!

Comment: i've added an answer with my comment above and additional info regarding your second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a complete answer without seeing the contents of ToolkitView, but I believe this is what is going on:

Your new view extendsToolkitView, and inherits the methods from that view. There is probably a `render` method that takes whatever template view that renders your template with data from whatever model is assigned to the view, (which in this case is  the `MUItem` template that you are loading through your `define` statement). Using `ToolKitView` as a "base" allows you to share common methods among your views, and tweak or extend them as need be.

In response to your comment regarding `showActiveMu`: when you create a new instance of this view, and assign a model to it, the view is able to access the model through `this.model`. In your case, the view's `showActiveMU` method will trigger an event, get the "code" attribute from the model, and pass that as an argument to any function listening for that event. More on backbone events [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Events).

```
var Model = new FooModel();
var muItem = new MUView({model: fooModel});

// listen for event triggered by the view's showActiveMU event
muitem.on('active:mu:selected', function (code) {
  console.log(code); // the code from the model assigned to muItem view
});
```